# Send Passkey through URL $_GET parameter

Tags: php, encryption

I have an API that spits out url's to a redirect page on my network. The url looks something like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/offers.php?country=US&offerID=5555
```

There is a few other parameters, but that's the jist of it. The problem is that users are abusing it and creating their own clicks with bots. I want to create a passkey system that forces users to use links from the API so that it is not abused.

Something like this:

api.php

```
<?php
$random_number=mt_rand(1,100);
$url="http://mydomain.com/offers.php?country=US&offerID=5555&key=".$random_number;
echo $url;
?>
```

offers.php

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
if($key<1 || $key>100)
die("Invalid key!");
?>
```

This is obviously a pretty dumb solution since it just uses a random number...but hopefully you see what I am trying to accomplish.

My idea was to encrypt a date string by the hour and encrypt it with a static hidden key. This would make the key change each hour and would be much more difficult for frauders. The only problem with this is if someone got the url from the API at 9:59, it would expire at 10:00 which is too short.

What is the best way to do this? The (ideal) key should be...

- Dynamic - it should change somewhat frequently.
- Lightweight - can't spend tons of resources just checking the key.
- Very difficult to crack/simulate.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: How did u solve this problem ? Mind sharing ?

Comment: I hashed all the parameters with an appended timestamp of the current hour and an appended salt. On the receiving end, I checked the hash against the current hour and the previous hour

Comment: Thanks. Just for me to understand you clearly. 1 - You DID NOT use sessions. 2 You  used a $_GET parameter ( data hashed + hour timestamp + salt ) and redirected to another page with this url.3. On the receiving page ( you already know the salt bcos its in a config file ? ), you extract the time from the hash and compare to current time within the range? Why cant u compare to the salt kept as a hidden field in the receiving page ? Sorry if my question is not good ?

Comment: Is it ok if i add yr solution to your post. I think its useful ?

Comment: 1. Is it ok if i add yr solution to your post. I think its useful ? 2. Also what kind of hash did u use ? bcrypt ?  or just md5 ? 3. Instead of current Hour - previous hour , what about time + 30s ? Is hidden fields in the receiving page / form a bad idea ?

Comment: @MarcoZen Post the solution as an answer, not as an addition to the question.

Comment: @seron - the answer came from him ->  user kmoney12

Answer (score 0):

What about a 1-time use hash, stored the current users' session?

Comment: If session usage was not possible, what other alternatives are available ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this. I am not recommending this as a secure or efficient solution, just something simple that prevented users from tampering with my urls.

```
public static function hashArray($arr, $timestamp)
    {
        $salt = "my-salt-here";
        $md5 = md5(http_build_query($arr) . $salt . $timestamp);
        return $md5;
    }


 //build the url
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H"); //links will last for about two hours
//if you want single-use links, you can add a random number to params

$params = ['offer'=>10, 'country'=>'US'];
$params['hash']=hashArray($params, $timestamp); //build hash and add it
$url = 'http://my-domain.com/click.php?'.http_build_query($params);


//check the hash
public static function checkHash($params, $hash)
    {
       //allow current or previous hour
        return $hash === hashArray($params, date('Y-m-d H')) 
               || $hash === hashArray($params, date('Y-m-d H', time()-3600)) 
    }

$params=$_GET;
$hash = isset($params['hash']) ? $params['hash'] : '';
unset($params['hash']);
checkHash($params, $hash);
```

Comment: Thank you for adding yr answer for the benefit of others. I dont have this problem current but am definitely appreciating the chance to learn more about  get urls.

Comment: Just wondering ... why did u allow a 2 hour window ? Any particular reason ?

Comment: Just my particular use case. I wanted users to query the API again rather than continuing to use the same link. At the same time, I wanted to be flexible and not block too much traffic unnecessarily.

Comment: Noted ... If the receiving page has a form ( which shouldnt be accessed directly ) , could this hash ( extracted from the get paramater in the url ) be used  as a hidden field to enable checking when the form is submitted as post ? I understand  using session +  post for such purposes but just wondering if your method can also be used ? In the session + post scenario, a token ( say a hash )  is in a hidden field and then posted and compared to the session value. In your scenario, can the hash from the get be used in a hidden field to be posted and compared to itself ?  Since no session used?